# How to remove all pseudo selectors from a CSS selector string using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, css-selectors, pseudo-class

For a script I'm doing I need to verify a CSS selector exists in the DOM. I'm wondering how to handle multiple `:pseudo` selectors with a generic rule.

Something like this is simple:

```
var selector = "div.foo div.bar:active"
```

which could be handled by

```
selector.split(":").shift(); // > div.foo div.bar
```

but when I have multiple selectors, I'm don't know how I could remove them. Something like this:

```
var selector = "div.foo:hover div.bar:after"
```

**Question:**
How would I remove all CSS pseudo selectors (`":something"`) from a string?

Comment: so you want only `div.foo` string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can remove them with a regular expression and `replace`:

```
selector = selector.replace(/::?[^ ,:.]+/g, '');
```

(The `::?` means one or two colons [you could also write it as `:{1,2}`], to handle `::after` and such; [full regex explanation](http://regex101.com/r/qR9qX1/1).)

That works for most situations, but if you have really complex pseudos with nested pseudos like `foo.bar:not(.baz:active)` (will be in CSS4), you'll need an actual CSS selector parser to handle them properly. While you could probably build a regex alternation that would handle *one* bit of nesting, in theory there can be multiple nesting, which is where a parser comes in.

But note that some of these pseudos **do** affect which element is chosen, such as `:nth-child`, so if your goal is to see if a matching element is in the DOM, you wouldn't want to remove those. So you might want to take the fairly pragmatic approach of listing the ones that you want to remove in a series of alternations, e.g.:

```
var toRemove = /:hover|:active|:before|:after|::?before|::?after|:and-so-on/g;
// ...
selector = selector.replace(toRemove, '');
```

There aren't all that many, and it eliminates the chance of removing important structural ones line `:nth-child`.

Comment: Nice. Getting to what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Also, I know it's just an example, but it's interesting to note that while `foo.bar:not(.baz:active)` is not currently valid CSS as of this writing, it will be in Selectors 4. `:not()` does currently accept lone pseudo-classes (`:not(:active)`), so it's still something you have to worry about.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - since you mention CSS selector parser... do you know one that is usable in a browser environment? Currently I'm using [JSCSSP](http://www.glazman.org/JSCSSP/), which seems unmaintained. Thanks!

Comment: @frequent: I don't, no, but [this project](https://github.com/reworkcss/css) is well spoken-of. It's a NodeJS module and so it will assume a fully ES5 environment, but I didn't immediately see that it was using a lot of NodeJS-specific APIs calls (I only glanced), so you may well be able to use it in a browser environment (as long as the browser has the relevant ES5 features, directly or through shims).

Comment: Ok. I will have a look. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Removing all pseudo-selectors will not solve your problem.

Take this example:

```
p:first-child {}

<div>
    <div></div>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

Since the paragraph is not the first child (and won't be unless the DOM changes), removing `:first-child` from the selector will give you a false positive match.

You need to remove only the pseudo-classes which are conditional upon things like mouse or keyboard interaction and the psuedo-elements. Then you need to special case `:link` and `:visited` so that the match anchors that are links and not ones that aren't (replacing them with an attribute selector of `[href]` is a slightly naïve approach, but should be good enough for all practical purposes).

You'll also need to make a decision for `:enabled` and `:disabled`. They aren't going to be changed by user interaction, but if you plan to toggle them with JS then you'll probably want to remove them.

Since there are a lot of conditions here, I'd write a function for it rather than attempting a simple regex.

Comment: Just FYI, while it is naïve, `a:link, a:visited` and `a[href]` are indeed exactly equivalent in HTML. As for `:enabled` and `:disabled`, you also have to account for the fact that some elements will never match either of those - those are the elements that have no notion of being enabled/disabled, such as non-form elements.